# Why I cant delete Users in my Database with my View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't delete users in my database. I dont know why Iam getting routing errors... I even asked ChatGPT, but that didn't helped at all.

Here is my code:

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  delete 'users/delete_user/:id', to: 'users#delete_user', as: 'delete_user'
  post '/newuser', to: 'users#create_new_user'
  get 'users/userlist'
  get 'users/newuser'
  get 'home/about'
  root 'home#index'
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"
end
```

view:

```
<h1>All Users</h1>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Username</th>
      <th scope="col">Password</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= user.users_id %></td>
      <td><%= user.username %></td>
      <td><%= user.userpw %></td>
      <td><%= user.email %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Delete', delete_user_path(user.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', delete_user_path(user.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end%>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

controller:

```
def delete_user
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to users_userlist_path
  end
```

This is the error:

No route matches [GET] "/users/delete_user/27"

(27 is the id of the user in my database)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please checkout the [tour], [ask] and [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). What is the error message that you were getting? Add that to your question to add context.

Comment: Sounds like the JS is not loading to enable that to be sent as a DELETE request which is most likely what you are trying to do. I assume the GET request happens when you click the delete button, right?  first thing, inspect the button and see the HTMl on it, that might help to post in here but this error is pretty common in this case.

Comment: yes, the GET requests happens when I click the delete button

Comment: not really sure I can offer a specific solve because it depends on your set up, but what I would recommend is googling something like, "delete button sending GET request Ruby on rails" and that should give you a thread to pull on to get it figured out, might help to add your specific rails version too

Comment: Most likely the Rails UJS isn't loaded properly. Put a `console.log` in your `application.js` to confirm it's running correctly, observe in the JavaScript console. The asset pipeline can be very fussy sometimes.

Comment: [You should not *force* a tag into your title.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) Because the tags appear below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for.

Comment: @tadman that assumes that this isn't Rails 7.

Comment: @max Turbo is a form of UJS, at least as far as what it does in spirit.

Comment: @tadman maybe in spirit but they aren't functionally interchangable or share any code heritage. Turbo is a much more ambitous design with some actual thought placed behind it. UJS is a pile of junk thats been plaguing rails since it ditched Prototype.

Comment: @tadman I was intially pretty sceptical about Turbo after seeing the monstrosities that people make with UJS but I have come to appreachiate it more and more. I'll have to see how I feel aftere seeing the juniors shoehorn everything into stimulus controllers for a few years.

Answer (score 0):

This attempt is just broken in so many ways so let me show how you actually do this in Rails 7:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users

  get 'home/about' # wut is this?
  root 'home#index'
end
```

This creates [the idomiatically correct routes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default). To destroy a user you send a DELETE request to the member path (`/users/:id`):

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # this is what you're calling "listuser".
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # DELETE /users/:id
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to action: :index
  end

  # ...

  private 

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

```
<h1>All Users</h1>

<table class="table">
  ...
  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
      ...
      <td><%= button_to('Delete', user, method: :delete, data: { turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?' }) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to('Edit', user) %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end%>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When you follow the conventions you can just pass a model instance to `link_to`, `button_to`, or `form_with` and it will deduce the route automatically. `button_to` creates an actual form so it does not rely on javascript to function (the confirmation still does though). The `method` option here still works the same as in previous versions of Rails.

In Rails 7 Turbo replaces the old Rails Unobtrusive Javascript Driver (UJS). While Turbo provides replacements for the functionality provided by Rails UJS the data attributes used are `data-turbo-method` and `data-turbo-confirm`.

```
<%= link_to(user, data: { turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?' }) %>
```

Comment: I understand that you're learning but Rails is a convention driven framework and you'll have a better learning experience if you use the guides instead of making stuff up as you go along and fight the framework.

Comment: Thanks Max, for your code. I started reading "Getting Started" on the Rails website and already realized that my code is completely broken. However, I have already got my own code running.

Comment: Even if its running its kind of a dead end. I would scrub that attempt and do it right, you'll find that the work you have done so far can be replaced pretty quickly.

Comment: Yeah I did that and started new. :)